# Active directory authentication

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm using the code below to authenticate a user in Active Directory, but the password is sending in clear text. How can I hash my password and then send it to Active Directory?

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, pwd);
try
{
   //Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
   object obj = entry.NativeObject;

   DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

   search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
   search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
   SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

   if (null == result)
   {
      return false;
   }

   //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
   _path = result.Path;
   _filterAttribute = (string)result.Properties["cn"][0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
}

return true;
```

Comment: This is a good question. Out of curiosity, what AuthenticationType are you using?

Comment: what is your mean of AuthenticationType, I'm using System.DirectoryServices; name space and mentioned code for Authenticating

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5, then I'd strongly recommend switching to using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace (read all about it: [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)).

Lots of things are a lot easier in `S.DS.AM` - like authenticating users:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
ctx.ValidateCredentials("test", "test", ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer);
```

The only way to do this securely is by specifying the `ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer` option to enforce using an SSL protected connection.

If you cannot move to .NET 3.5 and `S.DS.AM`, you need to check out the [`AuthenticationTypes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx) that you can define in the [fourth overloaded constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed.aspx) of `DirectoryEntry`:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = 
     new DirectoryEntry(path, username, pwd, 
                        AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer);
```

There's no other way to do this, I'm afraid - I don't think there's any way for you on the client-side to hash a password the same way Windwos Server / Active Directory do it, and pass in that hashed value...

Comment: Still failed :(. Maybe something wrong with me. So, if I have LDAP server `https://example.com`, what should I pass as `path` argument of `DirectoryEntry` constructor? Thanks

Comment: @BornToCode: you need to find out the proper **LDAP** path to your server - something like `LDAP://YourServer/DC=YourCOmpany,dc=com` - that https link doesn't really help much ...